# File.delete throws Errno:EACCESS Permission Denied in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, exception, file-io

The following code that is meant to delete lines that match a regular expression fails

```
def delete_entry(name)
    puts "Deleting #{name}.." if $DEBUG
    begin
      File.open("#{@file_name}.tmp", 'w') do |out_file|
        File.open(@file_name, 'r').each do |line|
          unless line =~ /^#{name},/
            out_file.print line
          else
            puts "Deleted #{line}!"
          end
        end
      end
      File.delete(@file_name)
      File.rename("#{@file_name}.tmp", @file_name)
    rescue Exception
      puts "Exception thrown in PhoneBook::delete_entry(#{name}): #{$!}"
    end
  end
```

The temporary file works just fine. The corresponding entries are deleted properly. But when I try to delete the old file, and rename the tmp to the new file, File.delete throws the following: (line 56 is the call to File#delete)

```
Exception `Errno::EACCES' at PhoneBook.rb:56 - Permission denied - file-io-sampl
es/phonebooks/test.csv
Exception thrown in PhoneBook::delete_entry(Mike): Permission denied - file-io-s
amples/phonebooks/test.csv
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is on Windows 7 using a NTFS filesystem if that helps matters.

Edit: As per Az's suggestion in the comments I added:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(File) { |f| p f if f.path == @file_name && !f.closed? }
```

Just before the call to File.delete.
The output is below:

```
C:\Pickaxe>ruby PhoneBook.rb true
Enter a phonebook!
test.csv
Using test.csv..
Open Called!
Name: Richard Sex: Male Age: 22
Name: Midori Sex: Female Age: 22
Name: Mike Sex: Male Age:  18
Name: Richard Sex: Male Age: 44
Deleting Mike..
Deleted Mike,Male, 18
!
#<File:file-io-samples/phonebooks/test.csv>
#<File:file-io-samples/phonebooks/test.csv>
Exception `Errno::EACCES' at PhoneBook.rb:56 - Permission denied - file-io-sampl
es/phonebooks/test.csv
Exception thrown in PhoneBook::delete_entry(Mike): Permission denied - file-io-s
amples/phonebooks/test.csv

C:\Pickaxe>
```

The two lines prefixed with # is the output of the ObjectSpace call.

Comment: Is the file read-only? (What is the output of `File.writable? @file_name`?)

Comment: Sounds like you may still have the file open when you try deleting it. Not sure though. I will look into it.

Comment: I thought of that as well, but at least under Linux it deletes just fine even if it's still open... (Edit: It seems to keep the file cached in some way though, which makes things... wierd.)

Comment: The file is not read only, other methods write to the file successfully. I think Larry might be correct. But I thought if you use File.open with a block, File.close is called automatically.

Comment: It is. Larry meant that you may have another copy of it open somewhere (I think).

Comment: @azgult: Deleting a file on a unixy system generally just removes the directory entry for that file, then when the reference count (look up how hard links work) on the actual file drops to zero the file's blocks are freed up. So deleting an open file isn't a problem. I don't know about Windows though.

Comment: Just in case it it because another copy of it is open, try running `ObjectSpace.each_object(File) { |f|  p f if f.path == @file_name && !f.closed? }` - That should print out any open files with your file name.

Comment: Ill update the question with the results, you're right, the File is still open. Also i dont know how to get the permissions on a windows system.

Comment: Updated, how do I close these? Can I call garbage collection early?

Comment: While it is possible to invoke garbage collection directly (`GC.start`), that won't help with your problem, as you still have a file *open*. This can't be the one in the block, so double check the rest of your code if at some point something forgets to close the file, or else your method is called between the points where it is opened and closed. Either way, I think I can safely say the problem is not in the part of your code we can see here.

Comment: I just did check. I used the ObjectSpace method to test if there was a file open before PhoneBook#delete_entry was called. And again just before File.delete. Same problem. I'm sure that the problem has to be in the method call.

Comment: Calling GC.start before File.delete works, but I'd rather find out why it doesnt automatically close as I call open with a block, which is supposed to ensure the file is closed after execution of the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out as I stated my last comment on the original post. The problem was is I wasn't calling open with a block and therefore did not benefit from the automatic f.close that comes with using File.open with a block.

To remedy this I used File.open do |file| file.each, instead of File.open(..).each

```
def delete_entry(name)
    puts "Deleting #{name}.." if $DEBUG
    begin
      File.open("#{@file_name}.tmp", 'w') do |out_file|
        File.open(@file_name, 'r+') do |file|
          file.each do |line|
            unless line =~ /^#{name},/
              out_file.print line
            else
              puts "Deleted #{line}!"
            end
          end
        end
      end
      ObjectSpace.each_object(File) { |f| p f if f.path == @file_name && !f.closed? } if $DEBUG
      File.delete(@file_name)
      File.rename("#{@file_name}.tmp", @file_name)
    rescue Exception
      puts "Exception thrown in PhoneBook::delete_entry(#{name}): #{$!}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes, that will do it. Instead of `File.open.each` try `File.foreach`

Answer (score 1):

As a general tip to anyone who finds this while trying to diagnose the error themselves, try deleting the file manually via the command line first.  That may show you that you have permissions issues on the file.